# What are the diagonals of the cartesian products of the following sets?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analytic-geometry

So, I'm doing Exercise 5.
[image]

Here is what I think about a).
[image]

So, we consider the first rectangle on the plane x y and the second on the plane x z. We take a point of the first rectangle and one of the second rectangle with the same coordinates. Proceeding like that, we obtain 'the diagonal of the parallelepiped.' So, I think it is more or less the correct answer. However, I cannot justify that.

If I am right, then b) is quite the same, but we have 'the diagonal plane of a three-dimensional coordinate system.'

I have no idea what to do with e). It seems impossible.

Comment: Your outputs from the previous exercises are $X^2$, not $X$ for the new question. So for part a, you need the diagonal of $[a,b]\times[a,b]$

Comment: @Andrei, are you sure? That's not clear to me. Nobody says that in a) we have two equal line segments. So, we might have $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$, and then the diagonal is empty. In that case, it would be reasonable to assume $X = X_1\times X_2$, and thus, we need to find $\textit{the diagonal of the Cartesian square }X^2\textit{of the set }X$, where $X$ is the rectangle. Sorry if I overthink the exercise. I will also check the original of the book in Russian. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think they ask you to make a plot in a 4D space

Comment: @Andrei, yeah, but as I found out today, for such a Cartesian product, there might be a geometric representation in a space with a lower dimension than the sum of the dimensions, for example, in a three-dimensional space.